# Why are these expressions with shifted delta functions not equal?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, distributions

I have the following equation

```
Exp[a-t]*DiracDelta[t-a] == DiracDelta[t-a]
```

which cannot be evaluated. However, if I plug in 0 for a:

```
In[1] = Exp[t]*DiracDelta[t] == DiracDelta[t]
Out[1] = True
```

This does not seem to work with values other than 0.

Of course, the equality with delta functions may be mathematically tricky, but in this case `Exp[a-t] == 1` for `a == t`, thus the first expression should yield `True` (in my opinion...).  How can I get to this value?

Comment: Strangely it works if you do `Simplify[Exp[a - t]*DiracDelta[t - a] == DiracDelta[t - a], 
 t - a == k]` where the second argument to Simplify is an assumption.

Comment: Set `a` to any constant value and it works.  It works for `a` algebraic if you integrate each side, which is what delta functions are for after all.

Comment: I am surprised it works at all for non integrals, because the formula you are using setting `a` to `t` is the formula for integrating delta functions.

Comment: The equation you try to check  without integration makes no sense! If it would be true you could conclude `Exp[t-a]=?=1` !?!